# How to Add Multiple choice for Dropdown list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I try to execute this code it shows like this. Can someone tell me why this multiple is not working for me? I already added Bootstrap dependency.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<select class="select" multiple>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">Eight</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? That's exactly what a `<select multiple>` looks like.,